# Allow a user access to their resources

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am developing a webapp with Spring/Hibernate and I would like to restrict access on a resource-specific basis. For example, a user will only be able to view/edit resources created by themselves or their "team". How does one implement this? Do I have to keep an additional attribute in my tables for an "owner" field? And if so, what if I want to allow access for some resources to a broad domain (a user can access their team's resources)? For others a more strict access control would be implemented (a user can only access their own resources)?

Is there any simple, good practice to incorporate this into all queries? (i.e. a filter maybe?)

Comment: Use security library like [spring-security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) or [java-ee](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partsecurity.htm#GIJRP)

Comment: but with spring security I got to secure URL or methods, not a resource specific security (Which depends on the database, its owner, its permissions, etc.) or am i wrong?

Comment: Check out Spring Security ACL (domain object security) : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html

Comment: I have the same question, and I found a better solution from another question: [Spring Data Rest: Return Resources of User]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834138/spring-data-rest-return-resources-of-user?rq=1) It seems a `user_id` attribute need to be added to entity.