# Spring Data Rest: Return Resources of User

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm creating a simple CRUD-App (a shoppinglist) with Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest. I have a resource: `ShoppingItem`. Is there an easy way to only return the resources which belong to the user who send the request? (Multiple User support) So a User only get his own ShoppingItems and not every ShoppingItem.
Or do i have to implement a Controller by myself, where i do this?

I found [Spring Data REST filtering data based on the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640487/spring-data-rest-filtering-data-based-on-the-user) this approach for filtering resources based on the user, but this won't help me for the repository endpoint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using spring secrity integration to handle your users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Spring security integration you can use ACL (maybe to heavy) or simple `postFilter` like following:

```
public interface ShoppingItemRepository extends CrudRepository<ShoppingItem, Long> {
    @PostFilter("filterObject.user.getId() == principal.id")
    @Override
    Iterable<ShoppingItem> findAll();   
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank your for this advice. Something like the post filter was the original thing i was looking for, so i will accept this as the answer, but when i do this, it wouldn,t be possible to get ALL shoppinItems as admin, would it?

Comment: I just read about postFilter in the spring docs. This should be exactly what i want. I'll try this later

Comment: Otherwise you can also have access to principal object in @query if you are using spring secu >= 4. And write your own request and filter user using hql (or SQL)

Comment: For admin issue. You just need to add in your postFilter a rules for role ADMIN to do not filter items for its role

Comment: The downside is that the filter fetches everything into memory and after that filters the objects, making things slow for complex objects. Furthermore, you're actually embedding your business logic in annotation value string. How are you planning to maintain it? And this will not solve the cron-jobs issues as there cron job is run with no user

Comment: @Kakawait imho providing sample with modifying Query would be better. This solution does have serious performance downsides.

Answer (score 1):

You better implement a Controller for several reasons:

- Imagine your application has some sort of management interface to look through all shopping lists (smth like admin account)
- Or you need to manipulate the shopping list in some cron-based job (where the uses is missing)
- business rules in code is better for learning new project (i.e. not all junior programmers can cope with spring magic easily)

Downsides to note:

- you will have to mimic current behavior of spring serialization ([you can use it on other side](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers))

Comment: Have a look at the postFilter suggestested by kakawait. This should make all this possible.

Comment: commented on his answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue recently, see [Spring Data Rest Override Repositories (Controllers vs AOP)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45531195/1203628)

The most elegant solution that I found was using AOP, this sample with QueryDSL and Spring Data REST Repositories:

```
@Aspect
@Transactional
@Component
public class FilterProjectsAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(*  com.xxx.ProjectRepository.findAll(..))")
    public void projectFindAll() {
    }

    @Around("projectFindAll()")
    public Object  filterProjectsByUser(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] instanceof Predicate) {
                Predicate predicate=(Predicate) args[i];
                BooleanExpression isProjectOwner =buildExpressionForUser()
                predicate = ExpressionUtils.allOf(isProjectOwner, predicate);
                args[i]=predicate;  //Update args
            }
        return pjp.proceed(args);
    }

}
```