# Spring Data Rest Override Repositories (Controllers vs AOP)

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-data-rest, querydsl

**Domain/Repository**

```
Project {
   User owner;
}

//Querydsl repositories
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ProjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Project>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QProject> {  
   default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QProject project) {
      (...)
   }
}
```

**Requeriment:**
filter data according to the authenticated user context:

- If user is `ROLE_PUBLIC` show projects according `predicate` and where user is the `owner`.
- If user is `ROLE_ADMIN` show projects according `predicate` filter.

I tried solved throught several alternatives:

**Option 1**: Override `@RepositoryRestController` as says [Spring DATA REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) doc:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class ProjectController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PagedResources<?> search(
        @QuerydslPredicate(root=Project.class ,bindings =ProjectRepository.class) Predicate predicate,
        @PageableDefault Pageable pageable, //
        @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {

        (...) // Update predicate wit user context

        projectRepository.findAll(predicate,pageagle);
        (...)
    }

}
```

This throw exception since the @QueryDslPredicat is not on the RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter list ([DATAREST-838](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-838)):

```
Failed to instantiate [com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate]: Specified class is an interface
```

The most similar argumentResolver into the list is `QuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but I dont know if it could be useful for this issue.

**Option 2**: This issue is a tipical cross-cutting concern so I tried apply AOP. Define Advice and update the args (Predicate):

```
@Around("this(com.xxx.yyy.repository.ProjectRepository)")
public void filterProjectsByUser(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
   Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
   // .. Find args Predicate, update it adding user profile expression and procceed.
  pjp.proceed(args);
}
```

The result is not the same as default Repository methods, instead of original JSON Object (with _embedded,page,_links), the response was:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8087/api/profile/projects"
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 3** 
Using `@RestController`:

```
@RestController
public class ProjectController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PagedResources<?> search(
        @QuerydslPredicate(root=Project.class ,bindings =ProjectRepository.class) Predicate predicate,
        @PageableDefault Pageable pageable, //
        @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {

        (...) // Update predicate wit user context

        projectRepository.findAll(predicate,pageagle);
        (...)
    }

}
```

Using the same path `@RequestMapping("/projects",...)` also override other endpoints (PUT,POST,...) and this is not desired. This forced to define another endpoint `("projects/search")`. 
I think that this workaround is not elegant and requires news endpoints. I am sure that exist a better alternative with Spring Data REST.

**Questions:**

- Any sugestions about how to solve this requeriment?
- How apply AOP to Spring Data REST to solve crosscutting requirements?
- Why @QuerydslPredicate at argument resolver?

*Spring Data REST  version 2.5.6*

*Although it has been resolved I would like to receive feedback and suggestions . I hope that QueryDSLPredicate annotation will be fixedn and the documentation will be improved with more samples about this issue.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get run the **Option 2** my error was not return `proceed` invocation result:

```
@Aspect
@Transactional
@Component
public class FilterProjectsAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(*  com.xxx.ProjectRepository.findAll(..))")
    public void projectFindAll() {
    }

    @Around("projectFindAll()")
    public Object  filterProjectsByUser(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] instanceof Predicate) {
                Predicate predicate=(Predicate) args[i];
                BooleanExpression isProjectOwner =buildExpressionForUser()
                predicate = ExpressionUtils.allOf(isProjectOwner, predicate);
                args[i]=predicate;  //Update args
            }
        return pjp.proceed(args);
    }

}
```